# After I set my wordpress server elastic ip in aws ec2,my wordpress can't request static file

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I  build a wordpress in aws EC2,everything goes well until I bind a Elastic IP 
to my wordpress server. The question is wordpress static file request is still the default aswec2 public dns, but I can see the page without css/js.

> Web server:apache2;Database: aws RDS(mysql);php version:5.3.10;My
>   wordpress address:[www.aoaostudio.com](http://www.aoaostudio.com) ;

Because before I bind a Elastic IP, I visit the aws public `dns:ec2-***-.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com`，my wordpress blog is ok!

I feel my apache2 configuration maybe wrong, the configuration file is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName www.aoaostudio.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/wordpress>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have no idea about php, maybe my question is fool, but I hope someone can give a help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably installed wordpress while you didn't have the elastic IP, so Wordpress remembered your URL as ec2-...

There is a tutorial for changing the URL of your Wordpress installation [here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/). Follow it, using `www.aoaostudio.com` as your URL.

Basically, what you need to do is to add these lines at the top of the `functions.php` file, right after the opening `<?php` tag:

```
update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://example.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'http://example.com' );
```

Then just load the admin login page a few times, and the URLs should update. It's very **important** that after all URLs are updated, you remove the code.